# Typescript issue: "Element implicitly has an 'any' type"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have such an object:

```
type TransactionType = 'income' | 'expense' | 'transfer' | 'balance'

const transactionTypes: Record<TransactionType, string> = {
  income: 'Income',
  expense: 'Expense',
  transfer: 'Transfer',
  balance: 'Balance',
}
```

I need to make such a data structure from it:

```
[
  {value: 'income', label: 'Income'},
  {value: 'expense', label: 'Expense'}
  {value: 'transfer', label: 'Transfer'}
  {value: 'balance', label: 'Balance'}
]
```

So, I'm adding this function:

```
function getTransactionTypes() {
  return Object.keys(transactionTypes).map((transactionType) => ({
    value: transactionType,
    label: transactionTypes[transactionType],
  }))
}
```

And on the line with `label: transactionTypes[transactionType]`, TS throws an error: `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Record<TransactionType, string>'.`

[Check the sandbox](https://replit.com/@natdavydova/NecessaryPopularOperatingsystem#index.ts)

How could I fix it?

Comment: `Object.keys()` returns `string[]` and not `TransactionType[]` because objects are allowed to have extra properties the compiler doesn't know about.  If you are positive there are no extra keys, you can use a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9AD7N).  See the questions this duplicates for more info.